# mod_proxy in apache not reassign ip

Tags: java, apache, soapui, mod-proxy

i have any web service application by jax-ws on address 192.168.1.1:7272/core , use mod_proxy apache for handle request from 192.168.1.1:8080/master to context 192.168.1.1:7272/core

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    # Disable proxying remote requests, we want a reverse proxy
  ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia On 
   <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>
    # Proxy requests to / into the correct context on localhost:8080
   ProxyPass /master http://192.168.1.1:7272/core
   ProxyPassReverse /master http://192.168.1.1:7272/core
```

in my application define client ip address and show

if use client by jax-ws , show correct my ip in app 192.168.1.5

if use soapui client show my ip in app "192.168.1.1" !

i use moddump_io for dump all request

soap-ui client

```
[Sat Jun 06 14:53:49 2015] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): POST /master/MessageRelayService HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

jax-ws client

```
[Sat Jun 06 14:54:38 2015] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): GET /master/MessageRelayService?wsdl HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

My problem is that it does not show the correct IP by soapui request ?